# Sorting Stack by implementing as Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, stack

I saw a problem on the web,i.e, I am trying to sort a stack using another reference stack in C. I tried to do it by implementing it as an array but it is not working.

(condition is that you have to use only arrays)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int MAXSIZE = 5;
int stack[5];
int tmpstack[5];
int tmp;
int top = -1;
int top2=-1;

int isempty(int A[],int B) {
     if(B == -1)
         return 1;
     else
         return 0;
}


int isfull(int A[],int B) {
       if(B == MAXSIZE)
           return 1;
       else
           return 0;
}

int pop(int A[],int B) {
        int data;
        if(!isempty(A,B)) {
           data = A[B];
           B = B - 1;
           return data;
         } 
        else {
             printf("Could not retrieve data, Stack is empty.\n");
             }
}

int push(int data,int A[],int B) {
          if(!isfull(A,B)) {
          B = B + 1;
          A[B] = data;
          } 
          else {
              printf("Could not insert data, Stack is full.\n");
                }
}
int sortStack(int stack[])
{
    int tmpStack[MAXSIZE];
  
    while (!isempty(stack,top))
    {
        int tmp = stack[top];
        pop(stack,top);
        while (!isempty(tmpstack,top2) && tmpstack[top2] > tmp)
              {
                 push(pop(tmpstack,top2),stack,top);
              }
        push(tmp,tmpstack,top2);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
int n ,a;
n=5;
for(int i = 0;i < n ; ++i){
      scanf("%d",&a);
      push(a,stack,top);
}
sortStack(stack);
while (!isempty(tmpstack,top2))
    {
        printf("%d ",tmpstack[top2]);
        pop(tmpstack,top2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I did here is that I made similar functions in arrays which we used in stacks only and we are supposed to use them only for implementing our stacks.

Comment: Please indent your code. Unindented code is very hard to understand

Comment: Start with the basics. Do your push & pop work correctly? I don't think they do. Fix those first.

Comment: If you replace your main with `push(42,stack,top); if (isempty(stack,top)) printf("still empty\n");` you should see a part of your problem.

Comment: @dratenik, Thanks sir, I got it. I am new to coding. I used pointers and it worked....thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it is not working"? What sort of inputs are you passing, and what final outputs are you getting?
Also, you might find it helpful to print the stack you are sorting during each cycle of the loop.